# How can you find all related/dependent resources in Azure?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azureportal

I am working on a script to collect all resources and put them into one resource group - however, the [command in Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/move-azresource?view=azps-3.7.0) used for moving resources works on a resource group by resource group basis. This means that if there are dependent/related resources in different resource groups, the command fails.

The alternative, then, is to group resources by their relation to one another and move them using some other method (probably manually through the portal/REST API.)

How can one then go through a list of resources in a subscription and group them by their dependency/relations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO one of the reason to introduce resource group is to try avoid such situation / scenario i.e., as per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/manage-resource-groups-portal#what-is-a-resource-group) Azure document, a resource group is a container that holds related resources for an Azure solution.

I believe a straight forward way or feature (to get list of dependent / related resources that are sitting in different resource groups in a subscription and group them by their dependency/relations) is currently not available or not supported. But I see [this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager/suggestions/40009819-show-dependency-tree-for-resources) feature request raised in UserVoice / feedback forum as a related one so if interested, you may upvote it or create a new feedback in there. In general, responsible Azure product / feature team would triage / start checking feasibility and prioritizing a received feedback based on various factors like number of votes a feedback receives, feasibility, open prioritized backlog items, etc.

On the other hand, as a workaround to accomplish this requirement for now, I suggest to try coming up with an automation (to get list of dependent / related resources that are sitting in different resource groups in a subscription and group them by their dependency/relations) by leveraging [Azure Platform logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/platform-logs-overview) (and fetching those logs at a particular time window of operation) as those logs provide detailed diagnostic and auditing information for Azure resources and the Azure platform they depend on.

Other related references:

- [Move resources to a new resource group or subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-resource-group-and-subscription)
- [Move operation support for resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-support-resources)
- [Troubleshoot moving Azure resources to new resource group or subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/troubleshoot-move)